# Using AJAX to pass form Submit variable to php page and return output html to DIV

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I have been reviewing a lot of the AJAX / PHP documentation and have a quick question for the community to help me understand the fundamentals. Here is a simple form, where a user submits a value. It is sent to a php calculator that squares the value and creates a little echo of the result.

I would like to learn how to simply include the php file into the div "target" after you click submit. Rather than pass back a value, I would like to include the php file in the div instead.

The forums have gotten me this far. Thanks to those who can look over and provide guidance.

**square.html:**

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        
         <head>
        <title> AJAX Insert test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        
        <body> 
         <form id="calculator" method="post">
           What Number would you like to square? 
           <input type="text" name="input_value">
           <input type="submit" value="Go">
            </form>
        
         <div id="target"></div>
                 
        
    <script>                
    $(function() { 
    $('#calculator').live('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stops form from submitting naturally
            $.ajax({
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: 'POST', //'GET' is default, set to 'POST' if you want.
                url: 'square.php',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#target").load("square.php");
                }
            });
        });            
    </script>
```

**square.php:**

```
<html>
<p>Results:<br><br></p>
</html>

<?php
$input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['input_value']);
$sum = $input * $input;

echo "You wrote " . $input ." <br>";
echo  $input . " squared = " .$sum . "<br><br>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to display the echo of the square.php, which means you have to do the following: `$("#target").load(response);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I still can’t get it to populate

Comment: I have got the response with $("target").html(response); !